# ActiveScaffold: attach JQuery Javascript event to newly-opened subform

Tags: jquery, event-handling, activescaffold

I want to attach a JQuery function to an input field in an update form. The form is standard ActiveScaffold, opened by clicking on the Edit link in the list view. How do I register the function -- what event signals that the subform has been opened and the DOM is ready? A new page has not been loaded so the onload() function doesn't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method, and you do not have to know when the element actually gets attached.

Comment: Thanks, that's a great feature I didn't know about. It does not quite fit what I need, though, because (I think) I need to run the JQuery statements when the form opens, not when someone clicks on it. For example, I want to convert an input to autocomplete ... $( "#country_name" ).autocomplete({source: availableTags}). I think that should occur before the user tries to click on the input, right?

Comment: @Mike, you are correct. The live method is to handle events. I am not a ruby guy so do not know the internals of the activescaffold system. Check to see if the have a callback option when they launch their ajax call to fetch the form (*that would be called once the form gets displayed*)..

Comment: In practice it seems to work fine by attaching autocomplete when the input is clicked, even when I tab into the input rather than clicking. I haven't seen anything about callbacks but could ask in the ActiveScaffold group.